# Subdomains, redirects and static files with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to set up a specific configuration with Express and I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to make everything work. I've looked at tons of resources and questions on SO but no dice. I'm hoping if I explain all I'm trying to do someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Here's what I want:

1. For `sub.domain.com`, do some logic and serve static files from `/public/sub/`;
2. For `domain.com/sub/`, rewrite the URL to `sub.domain.com` then proceed with the same logic as in 1;
3. For `domain.com`, serve static files from `/public/`.

Whatever I do, I run into issues with one of these things...
Here's my current code:

**(update based on [Stock Overflaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269732/stock-overflaw)'s answer)**

```
const baseUrl = '/bundle/cloud/public/', // This is needed as I'm hosting on NodeChef and that's their folder structure
  vhost = require('vhost'), // Also tried with express-subdomain
  express = require('express'),
  routerMain = express.Router(),
  routerSub = express.Router(),
  staticOpts = { extensions: ['html', 'htm'] };

//sub.domain.com
routerSub.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('routerSub called');
  next();
});
routerSub.use(express.static(baseUrl + 'sub/', staticOpts));

// domain.com
routerMain.get('/sub', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('https://sub.domain.com/');
});
routerMain.use(express.static(baseUrl, staticOpts));

// Connect routers
app.use(vhost('sub.domain.com', routerSub));
app.use(routerMain);
```

Here are the results:

```
✅ domain.com/          /public/index.html
✅ domain.com/file      /public/file.html
✅ domain.com/sub/      redirect to sub.domain.com/ (but then, see below)
✅ sub.domain.com/      /public/sub/index.html
❌ domain.com/sub/file  /public/sub/file.html (should redirect to sub.domain.com/file)
```

When calling sub.domain.com/, I get 4 "routerSub called" logs, which makes sense since there's 1 for the html, and then 1 for css and 2 for js, <del>despite the css and js files not making being read</del>.

<del>The css tag in /public/sub/index.html is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.min.css">`, and /public/sub/style.min.css exists, so I don't understand why it can't find it. Plus, I'm specifying the extension so I shouldn't need to add `'css'` to `staticOpts`.</del>

**Update:** css and js files weren't served when reaching sub.domain.com/ simply because of my browser's cache. /facepalm

The issue that remains is that when you try to access a file by entering its full path like `domain.com/sub/file.html` it does serve it, when it should first redirect you to `sub.domain.com/file`.

That's it...

Anyone know how to help with that? 
Cheers.

Comment: In your update, `staticOpts` hasn't changed (`'css', 'js'` to be added). However the domain-related routing should be OK (you should see your server console logging `routerSub called` when calling `sub.domain.com` or `domain.com/sub`). Show your outputs when trying to call both?

Comment: I updated again to make everything clearer (hopefully).
For both `sub.domain.com` and `domain.com/sub`, I get 4 "routerSub called" logs... (I was surprised by this but it actually makes sense: one for the html file itself, one for the css, 2 for js scripts)

I tried adding the extensions to the list, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: oh my GOSH the css issue is just browser cache. I'll update the question again. There's still one redirection issue...

Comment: Updated my post about the redirection issue, the route declaration/redirection is incomplete for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

> while sub.domain.com does get me /public/sub/index.html, I can't get the css and js files that are required for that page

This is probably due to `staticOpts = { extensions: ['html', 'htm'] };`, you might want to try adding `'css', 'js'` to that list.

> I feel like it's trying to get static files from /public/

Use some `console.log` to see which handler is called, if any - and if the previous point I made didn't fix this issue.

> domain.com/sub/ does not redirect at all

I think you want to use `res.redirect` instead of `res.location` (which only sets the response header, not the HTTP code). And apparently you don't need `next()`.

Also, I couldn't make this setup work with `router.use(subdomain('sub', routerSub))`, I think it's because `router` is not itself wrapped in a `subdomain` call*. However, declaring `app.use` instad of `router.use` did the job.

*: pure hypothesis there, but the only way they use "imbricated" routers is when they're doing multi-level subdomains, and they show no root level router at the end (i.e. no router that is not wrapped in a `subdomain` call).

Here is a working and simplified mock of your domain redirection:

```
// declare stuff
const express = require('express');
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
const router = express.Router();
const routerSub = express.Router();
const app = express();
// make handlers to be tested
routerSub.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('routerSub called');
  res.send('ok');
});
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('router called');
  res.redirect('http://api.myhost.localdomain:3000');
});
// register everything properly
app.use(subdomain('api', routerSub));
app.use(router);
// start server
app.listen(3000);
```

I set up my `/etc/hosts` file with `myhost.localdomain` and `api.myhost.localdomain` pointing to localhost. (Obviously.)

Hope this helps!

## EDIT

Indeed I considered only the `subdomain` thing, forgot about the routes themselves. This should help:

```
routerMain.get(['/sub', '/sub/*'], (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('https://sub.domain.com/' + (req.params[0] ? req.params[0] : ''));
});
// or, another approach easing a pass-through for the query string as well:
routerMain.get(/^(?:(\/sub\/).+|(\/sub\/?))$/, (req, res) => {
  const substr = req.params[0] ? req.params[0].length : req.params[1].length;
  res.redirect('https://sub.domain.com/' + req.originalUrl.substr(substr));
});
```

Comment: Thanks!

I updated my code based on your suggestions, but it still doesn't work. I tried using vhost instead of express-subdomain, and added css & js to the list of extensions... nothing. (The extensions are specified in the html anyway.)

Will add code to an update in the question, I forgot the formatting in comments is so restricted.

Comment: (just a quick update, something else came up and I couldn't try your new solution, I will do asap and accept the answer if it works)